# How do i make Bar Chart of a subset of counts of categorical Column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, data-science

I have a Fifa 19 Dataset with data on more than 1000 players hailing from more than 100 countries. I want to make a bar chart showing the distribution of nationalities where number of players is greater than 3. Here is what I have tried:

```
nation = fifa_19[fifa_19['Nationality'].value_counts()>=3]
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.countplot(nation, order = fifa_19['Nationality'].value_counts().index)
plt.title('Distribution of Nationalities of players')
plt.xlabel('Nationality') 
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
```

and I get this error:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

I am making a sample DataFrame and adding it here.

```
fifa_19 = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['A','B','C','D','E','F','E','G','H'],'Nationality':['USA','USA','USA','Canada','Pakistan','India', 'Brazil','Brazil','Brazil']})
```

If someone can help me, It will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your code the `.value_counts()` Series won't work as an index into the `fifa_19` dataframe. Instead:

```
nation = fifa_19['Nationality'].value_counts()
nation = nation.loc[nation >= 3]

plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.barplot(data=nation, x="Country", y="Frequency", order = fifa_19['Nationality'].value_counts().index)
plt.title('Distribution of Nationalities of players')
plt.xlabel('Nationality') 
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
```

**Note**: If you don't want the empty values for nationalities that don't meet the 3 player threshold, change this line:

```
sns.barplot(data=nation, x="Country", y="Frequency", order = fifa_19['Nationality'].value_counts().index)
```

to

```
order = pd.DataFrame(fifa_19['Nationality'].value_counts().index).join(nation["Country"], how="inner")["Country"]
sns.barplot(data=nation, x="Country", y="Frequency", order = order)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I am getting a result, but it is a bar chart showing the distribution of numbers of players. For example, if 2 countries have 156 players. then the horizontal axis is "156" and vertical is 2. I was hoping for the distribution of nationalities.

Comment: Replace `sns.barplot...` with `sns.countplot(nation["Frequency"])`. Although then your x and y label don't make sense/need to be changed.

Comment: I still had issues, but I figured it out. The issue was sns.countplot(), I don't need a value_counts() inside sns.countplot() as countplot does it itself. value_counts() will work with sns.barplot() but only after resetting the index so i have 2 different columns.